# Prove that $\frac{1}{1^4}+\frac{1}{2^4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^4} \le 2-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: inequality, summation

I have to show: $\displaystyle\frac{1}{1^4}+\frac{1}{2^4}+...+\frac{1}{n^4} \le 2-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ for natural $n$

I tried to show it by induction (but I think it could be possible to show it using some ineqaulity of means) so for $n=1$ we have $1=1$ so inequality holds then I assume it's true for $n$ and for $n+1$ my thesis is $\displaystyle\frac{1}{1^4}+\frac{1}{2^4}+...+\frac{1}{(n+1)^4} \le 2-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$

I know that: 
$\displaystyle\frac{1}{1^4}+\frac{1}{2^4}+...+\frac{1}{(n+1)^4} \le 2-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^4}$ but later I'm not sure if I have to show

$\displaystyle2-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^4}\le2-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$ or should be $\ge$

Comment: Should be $\le$.

Comment: You want to show that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^4}\ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$, or equivalently that $\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}}\ge \frac{1}{(n+1)^4}$. Rationalize the numerator. There is a lot of slack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to show that
$$2-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac1{(n+1)^4}\le 2-\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}.\tag{1}$$
If (1) is true, then using induction hypothesis one gets
$$1+\frac1{2^4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^4}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^4}\le 2-\frac1{\sqrt{n}}+\frac1{(n+1)^4}\le 2-\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}},$$
and we are done by induction.

Showing (1) should be easy since
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}=\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}=\frac1{\sqrt{n(n+1)}(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}.$$

Comment: OK so all comes down to show $\displaystyle \frac{1}{(n+1)^4}\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$ have you idea how show it ?

Comment: Multiplicative conjugate...

Answer (score 1):

You should show its:

$\displaystyle2-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^4}\le2-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$

The other ways does not help your proof (think about it for a while)

Answer (score 1):

If we are allowed to use tools from the calculus, we can show that the result holds at $n=1,2$, and then use the fact that
$$\frac{1}{3^4}+\frac{1}{4^4}+\frac{1}{5^4}+\cdots\lt \int_2^\infty x^{-4}\,dx.$$

From this we can conclude that our sum $S_n$ is always less than $1+\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{24}$.